# Помогите найти ошибку в коде задачи

Tags: c++, строки, char

Сама задача:

> Дана строка, заменить в ней символ `$` на введённое пользователем имя.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int d,p=0,d1;
    char S[100];
    char name[20];
    char bufer[250];
    cin.getline(name, 20);
    cin.getline(S, 20);
    d = strlen(S);
    d1 = strlen(name);

    for (int i = 0; i <= d; i++)
        if (S[i] == '$')
        {
            for(int g = 0; i <= d1; i++)
                bufer[p] = name[g];
            p = p + d1;
        }
        else
        {
            p++;
            bufer[p] = S[i];
        }

    cout << bufer<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: отформатируйте код

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

Замените на

```
void replace(string&s, const string& rep)
{
    for(size_t pos = s.find('$'); pos != string::npos;
        pos = (s.replace(pos,1,rep), s.find('$')));
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string s = "Hello, $ and $!";
    string rep = "bro";
    replace(s,rep);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

и не мучайтесь :)

Если приспичило через `char*` и гарантируете, что буфера хватит - то

```
void replace(char * buf, const char * rep)
{
    char * c;
    int len = strlen(rep);
    while(c = strchr(buf,'$'))
    {
        memmove(c+len,c+1,strlen(c+1)+1);
        memcpy(c,rep,len);
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char buf[256] = "Hello, $ and $!";
    char * rep = "bro";
    replace(buf,rep);
    cout << buf << endl;
}
```

Оба варианта **НЕ** обрабатывают рекурсивный `$` - т.е. в подмене его быть не должно!

Answer (score 0):

Для начала желательно писать правильные английские слова в качестве идентификаторов. Я бы заменил идентификатор `bufer` на `buffer`

```
char buffer[250];
     ^^^^^^
```

Если вы в программе используете стандартные C функции такие, как, например, `strlen`, то следует включить заголовок `<cstring>`

```
#include <cstring>
```

На самом деле, когда вы имеете дело со строками, то обычно можно обойтись без этой функции и ориентировать на завершающий ноль строки. Иначе вызов `strlen` при последовательной обработке строки, как это имеет место в вашей программе, лишь отнимает время.

В этом цикле

```
for(int g = 0; i <= d1; i++)
    bufer[p] = name[g];
```

вы пытаетесь скопировать в `bufer` помимо других символов также завершающий 0, что на самом деле не надо делать.

А самое главное - вы не увеличиваете индексы `p` и `g`, поэтому копирования не происходит, тем не менее индекс `i`, который не должен увеличиваться, увеличивается.

Правильно было бы записать

```
        for(int g = 0; g < d1; g++)
            bufer[p++] = name[g];
```

а следующее после цикла предложение

```
        p = p + d1;
```

удалить.

В этом блоке кода вы должны увеличивать индекс `p` (кстати сказать, это плохое имя для индекса) после предложения с присваиванием, а не до него.

```
    else
    {
        p++;
        bufer[p] = S[i];
    }
```

Вы могли бы все сделать с помощью стандартных функций таких, как, `strchr`, `memcpy` и `strcpy`, но если вы хотите поупражняться в циклах то основной код программы может выглядеть следующим образом

```
size_t i = 0;

for (size_t j = 0; S[j] != '\0'; j++ )
{
    if (S[j] == '$')
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; name[k] != '\0'; k++)
        {
            buffer[i++] = name[k];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        buffer[i++] = S[j];
    }
}

buffer[i] = '\0';
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char S[100] = "Hello $. What are you $ going to say?";
    char name[20] = "John Shepard";
    char buffer[250];

    size_t i = 0;
    for (size_t j = 0; S[j] != '\0'; j++ )
    {
        if (S[j] == '$')
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; name[k] != '\0'; k++)
            {
                buffer[i++] = name[k];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[i++] = S[j];
        }
    }

    buffer[i] = '\0';

    std:: cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
Hello John Shepard. What are you John Shepard going to say?
```

Как можно видеть, программа никаких функций не использует, чтобы получить результат.